# Sympy get valid integer range for each variable in expression

Tags: python, sympy

Given that I have the following expression:

```
from sympy import *
a,b,c,d = var('a b c d')
variables = { 'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d }
string = "(a > 1548) | (a > 2090) | (b > 2662) | ((c > 838) & (c < 1801)) | ((d > 2770) & (d < 3448))"
expr = eval(string,variables)
expr
```

```
(a > 1548) | (a > 2090) | (b > 2662) | ((c > 838) & (c < 1801)) | ((d > 2770) & (d < 2900))
```

I want to get the valid value range for each variable if each variable can be between 1 and 3000.
In other words:

```
valid_expr = expr & ((1 <= a) & (a <= 3000)) & ((1 <= b) & (b <= 3000)) & ((1 <= c) & (c <= 3000)) & ((1 <= d) & (d <= 3000))
```

How do I get the range for each variable?

I want to somehow get an output similar to

```
{
  'a': [1548,3000],
  'b': [2662,3000],
  'c': [838,1801],
  'd': [2770,2900]
}
```

Comment: If `a` can be >1548 or >2090, why should the final output use the 2090 value? Shouldn't it be the less restrictive of the two?

Comment: Also, are you bound to using strings and `eval` like that?

Comment: @jared typo sorry, a should be between 1558 and 3000. The expression/`string` is constructed programmatically, so eval was the most convenient i thought. But I am not bound to use `eval`.

Comment: I don't think sympy can do this directly. I think you might need to manually parse the expression to get the ranges..

Answer (score 2):

The current SymPy master branch has some functions for linear programming:

```
In [15]: from sympy.solvers.simplex import linprog, lpmin, lpmax

In [16]: lpmin(a, [a>=1549, a>=1, a<=3000])
Out[16]: (1549, {a: 1549})

In [17]: lpmax(a, [a>=1549, a>=1, a<=3000])
Out[17]: (3000, {a: 3000})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have Or arguments that are univariate so you can separate those and then combine them with the range of interest with the And function:

```
from collections import defaultdict as D
u = D(list)
for i in expr.args:
    u[oi.free_symbols.pop()].append(i)
for v in ordered(u):
    print(v, (Or(*u[v]).as_set()&Interval(1,3000)))
```

This outputs intervals (but if you prefer to have inequalities, use the `as_relational(x)` method of Interval to convert them):

```
a Interval.Lopen(1548, 3000)
b Interval.Lopen(2662, 3000)
c Interval.open(838, 1801)
d Interval.Lopen(2770, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the range for each variable?

I don't think this is easily done in sympy. As a workaround, if we assume that each variable is an integer in the range [1, 3000] we could use a brute-force approach like this:

```
from sympy import symbols, sympify, Or
from sympy.logic.boolalg import BooleanTrue

a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d')

string = "(a > 1548) | (a > 2090) | (b > 2662) | ((c > 838) & (c < 1801)) | ((d > 2770) & (d < 3448))"
expr = sympify(string)

def find_valid_range(variable):
    lower = None
    upper = None
    min = 1
    max = 3000
    for i in range(min, max+1):
        res = expr.subs(variable, i)
        if isinstance(res, Or):
            if lower is not None:
                upper = i-1
                break
            continue
        assert isinstance(res, BooleanTrue)
        if lower is None and res:
            lower = i
            continue
        if lower is not None and not res:
            upper = i-1
            break
    if lower is None:
        raise Exception("No range found")
    else:
        if upper is None:
            upper = max
    return [lower, upper]

# Finding the valid range for each variable
valid_ranges = {
    'a': find_valid_range(a),
    'b': find_valid_range(b),
    'c': find_valid_range(c),
    'd': find_valid_range(d)
}

print(valid_ranges)
```

**Output**:

```
{'a': [1549, 3000], 'b': [2663, 3000], 'c': [839, 1800], 'd': [2771, 3000]}
```